# Is it possible to reverse a linked list in-place without allocating any nodes?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to understand how ownership in Rust works with regard to linked lists. I have this code:

```
struct Node {
    value: i32,
    next: Option<Box<Node>>
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = Box::new(Node {value: 1, next: None});
    let mut y = Box::new(Node {value: 2, next: Some(x)});
}
```

which creates a linked list y -> x -> null. Is it possible to switch this around in-place, so that we end up with x -> y -> null without allocating any new nodes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Absolutely.  Ownership in this case is pretty simple: the `main` function owns `y`, which owns `x`, and owners can mutate the things they own.

To swap two nodes `a` and `b` where `a` → `b` → …, you just need to do the following:

- Disconnect `b` from `a`, so that you have `a` → ⊥ and `b` → ….
- Remove everything following `b`; call this `c…`.  You now have `b` → ⊥, and `c` → ….  Note that `c` might be empty, or it might be a long list; we don't care.
- `a` and `b` are now alone, and don't connect to anything else, so you can just exchange their contents, swapping them in place.
- Attach `c` to the end of `a`, giving you `a` → `c` → ….
- Attach `a` to the end of `b`, giving you `b` → `a` → ….

No new nodes need allocating, and this can be transcribed pretty much directly into Rust:

```rust
struct Node {
    value: i32,
    next: Option<Box<Node>>
}

impl Node {
    pub fn swap_with_next(&mut self) {
        use std::mem::swap;

        match self.next.take() {
            Some(mut next_node) => {
                let next_next = next_node.next.take();
                swap(self, &mut next_node);
                next_node.next = next_next;
                self.next = Some(next_node);
            },
            None => {
                // Uh-oh, there's nothing to swap *with*!
                panic!("cannot swap with nothing");
            }
        }
    }

    pub fn show(&self) {
        print!("{:?}", self.value);
        if let Some(next) = self.next.as_ref() {
            print!(" -> ");
            next.show();
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut w = Box::new(Node { value: 0, next: None });
    let mut x = Box::new(Node { value: 1, next: Some(w) });
    let mut y = Box::new(Node { value: 2, next: Some(x) });

    y.show();
    println!("");

    y.swap_with_next();
    y.show();
    println!("");
}
```

Finally, I'd be remiss if I didn't point you toward [Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](http://cglab.ca/~abeinges/blah/too-many-lists/book/).